# Clickable poster after video play

Tags: jquery, html, video

I intend to have w3html5.gif with clickable hotspots. currently my code is:

```
<video controls poster="/images/w3html5.gif">
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.

You might just want to wrap your `<video>` tag in an anchor tag, something will looks like this:

`<a href="#"><video>...</video></a>`

Comment: I need to make the image clickable on different points. Point for Daily, Weekly.

Comment: I need 3 different links on the image